# Generating a Lua table with random non repeating numbers

Tags: lua

I'm looking to generate a table of random values, but want to make sure that none of those values are repeated within the table.

So my basic table generation looks like this:

```
numbers = {}

for i = 1, 5 do
    table.insert(numbers, math.random(20))
end
```

So that will work in populating a table with 5 random values between 1-20.  However, it's the making sure none of those values repeat is where I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to *shuffle* an array of numbers and then take the first n numbers. The wrong way to go about shuffling an array is to maintain a list of previously generated random numbers, checking against that with each newly generated random number before adding it to the final array. Such a solution is O(n^2) in time complexity when iterating over the array during the check; this will be painful for large arrays, or for small arrays when many must be created. Lua has constant time array access since tables are really hash tables, so you could get away with this, except: sometimes many random numbers will need to be tried before a suitable one (that has not already been used) is found. This can be a real problem near the end of an array of many random numbers, i.e., when you want 1000 random numbers and have filled all but the last slot, how many random tries (and how many iterations of the 999 numbers already selected) will it take to find the only number (42, of course) that is still available?

The right way to go about shuffling is to use a shuffling algorithm. The [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is a common solution to this problem. The idea is that you start at one end of an array, and swap each element with a random element that occurs later in the list until the entire array has been shuffled. This solution is O(n) in time complexity, thus much less wasteful of computational resources.

Here is an implementation in Lua:

```lua
function shuffle (arr)
  for i = 1, #arr - 1 do
    local j = math.random(i, #arr)
    arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
  end
end
```

Testing in the REPL:

```
> t = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
> table.inspect(t)
1 = 1
2 = 2
3 = 3
4 = 4
5 = 5
6 = 6
> shuffle(t)
> table.inspect(t)
1 = 4
2 = 5
3 = 1
4 = 6
5 = 2
6 = 3
```

This can easily be extended to create lists of random numbers:

```lua
function shuffled_numbers (n)
  local numbers = {}
  for i = 1, n do
    numbers[i] = i
  end
  shuffle(numbers)
  return numbers
end
```

REPL interaction:

```
> s = shuffled_numbers(10)
> table.inspect(s)
1 = 9
2 = 5
3 = 3
4 = 4
5 = 7
6 = 6
7 = 2
8 = 10
9 = 8
10 = 1
```

If you want to see what is happening during the shuffle, add a `print` statement in the `shuffle` function:

```lua
function shuffle (arr)
  for i = 1, #arr - 1 do
    local j = math.random(i, #arr)
    print(string.format("%d (%d) <--> %d (select %d)", i, arr[i], j, arr[j]))
    arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]
  end
end
```

Now you can see the swaps as they occur if you recall that in the above implementation of `shuffled_numbers` the array `{ 1, 2, ..., n }` is the starting point of the shuffle. Note that sometimes a number is swapped with itself, which is to say that the number in the current unselected position is a valid choice, too. Also note that the last number is automatically the correct selection, since it is the only number that has not yet been randomly selected:

```
> s = shuffled_numbers(10)
1 (1) <--> 5 (select 5)
2 (2) <--> 10 (select 10)
3 (3) <--> 5 (select 1)
4 (4) <--> 9 (select 9)
5 (3) <--> 8 (select 8)
6 (6) <--> 9 (select 4)
7 (7) <--> 8 (select 3)
8 (7) <--> 10 (select 2)
9 (6) <--> 9 (select 6)
> table.inspect(s)
1 = 5
2 = 10
3 = 1
4 = 9
5 = 8
6 = 4
7 = 3
8 = 2
9 = 6
10 = 7
```

---

Obtaining a selection of 5 random numbers between 1 and 20 is easy enough to accomplish using the `shuffle` function; one of the virtues of this approach is that the shuffling operation has been abstracted to an O(n) procedure which can shuffle any array, numeric or otherwise. The function that calls `shuffle` is responsible for supplying the input and returning the results.

A simple solution for more flexibility in the range of random numbers returned:

```lua
-- Take the first N numbers from a shuffled range [A, B].
function shuffled_range_take (n, a, b)
  local numbers = {}
  for i = a, b do
    numbers[i] = i
  end
  shuffle(numbers)

  return { table.unpack(numbers, 1, n) }
  -- table.unpack won't work for very large ranges, e.g. [1, 1000000]
  -- You could instead use this for arbitrarily large ranges:
  -- local take = {}
  -- for i= 1, n do
  --   take[i] = numbers[i]
  -- end
  -- return take
end
```

REPL interaction creating a table containing 5 random values between 1 and 20:

```
> s = shuffled_range_take(5, 1, 20)
> table.inspect(s)
1 = 1
2 = 10
3 = 4
4 = 8
5 = 20
```

---

But, there is a disadvantage to the shuffle method in some circumstances. When the number of elements needed is small compared with the number of available elements, the above solution must shuffle a large array to obtain comparatively few random elements. The shuffle is O(n) in the number of elements *available*, while the memoization method is roughly O(n) in the number of elements *chosen*. A memoization method like that of [@AlexanderMashin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64071160/6879826) performs poorly when the goal is to create an array of 20 random numbers between 1 and 20, because the final numbers chosen may need to be chosen many times before suitable numbers are found. But when only 5 random numbers between 1 and 20 are needed, this problem with duplicate choices is less of an issue. This approach seems to perform better than the shuffle, up to about 10 numbers needed from 20 random numbers. When more than 10 numbers are needed from 20, the shuffle begins to perform better. This break-even point is different for larger numbers of elements to choose from; for 1000 available elements, parity is reached at about 700 chosen. When performance is critical, testing is the only way to determine the best solution.

Comment: This answer assumes that the number of number in array and the maximum value of a number is the same, doesn't it? Is it what is needed?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin -- good catch; the important part of my answer was the shuffle procedure which can be used in many ways, but I have added an update showing how you could create a random list of 5 numbers between 1 and 20.

Comment: Performance of this solution can still be improved by about 60% (when `n = 5, a = 1, b = 20`, more with greater `b`). Remove `for i = a, b do numbers[i] = i end` and replace `arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]` with `arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j] or j, arr[i] or i`.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin -- how do you figure that? I tried my `shuffle` against a version using your conditional assignment trick, and for 16000000 numbers mine was consistently 1 second faster on my laptop (4.5s vs 5.5s). Unless I just botched something in the test, I would guess that the problem with your suggestion is that there are two comparisons and potentially an allocation in a tight loop. Filling the array to be shuffled beforehand takes only a tiny fraction of a second, and has no effect on the shuffle time.

Comment: I ran two variants each in a loop of one million or so iterations (already overwritten the file); your variant took ~41.77 sec, mine, ~15.84 sec; both without `print`. When I increased `b` and decreased the number of loops, it became ~12.780323 and ~1.56. The time is measured as difference between two call of `os.clock()`. Lua 5.1.5.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin -- I think that you have made a mistake in testing those functions. I have run many tests, and they all say the same thing: your suggested optimization is slower. This is because you are putting two compares and a rehash inside of a loop to save the front-end work of filling an array. I am not getting anything even close to the discrepancy you report, but on my machine taking the first 5 numbers from a shuffled array of 20 numbers 2,000,000 times in a loop takes my method 9.9s, and it takes yours 13.3s. It did take my method 47.5s to do _10,000,000_ iterations like this...

Comment: @AlexanderMashin -- ... so I wonder if you accidentally tested my method at 10,000,000 iterations instead of 1,000,000. I also tested with large _b_: on my machine taking the first 5 numbers from a shuffled array of 10,000 numbers 10,000 times in a loop takes my method 16.5s, and it takes your method 20.5s.

Comment: It could be ten million, but for both variants (it was a variable).

Comment: @AlexanderMashin -- Oh, you have been testing the function in my answer against the function in your answer, yes? In the comments above I was testing [the optimization you suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64069321/generating-a-lua-table-with-random-non-repeating-numbers/64071746#comment113360239_64071746), which is not an optimization at all. It should come as no surprise that your solution below is faster for a small selection from a large range of random numbers; there is a break-even point. Try your function with `fill_table(1000,1000)` instead of `fill_table(5, 1000)`.

Comment: No, I was testing your solution with pre-filled table against your solution without one. I restored the test at https://traditio.wiki/Module:Test80 (similar results in MediaWiki environment and in plain Lua). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin -- your implementation of `shuffle2` was not executing the shuffle code in the loop body, so the shuffle code was never timed. [Here is an Ideone link explaining some of the issues.](https://ideone.com/cseiST)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222222/discussion-between-alexander-mashin-and-ex-nihilo).

Answer (score 1):

```lua
numbers = {}
local i = 1;

while i<=5 do
    n = 0
    local rand = math.random(20)
    for x=1,#numbers do
      if numbers[x] == rand then
        n = n + 1
      end
    end
    if n == 0 then
      table.insert(numbers, rand)
      i = i + 1
    end
    n = 0
end
```

the method I used for this process was to use a `for` to scan each of the elements in the table and increase the variable `n` if one of them was equal to the random value given, so **if x was different from 0, the value would not be inserted in the table**  and would not increment the variable `i` (I had to use the `while` to work with `i`)

if you want to print each of the elements in the table to check the values you can use this:

```lua
for i=1,#numbers do
  print(numbers[i])
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest an alternative method based on the fact that it is easy to make sets in Lua: they are just tables with true values.

```
-- needed is how many random numbers in the table are needed,
-- maximum is the maximum value of a random non-negtive integer.
local function fill_table( needed, maximum )
    math.randomseed ( os.time () ) -- reseed the random numbers generator
    local numbers = {}
    local used = {} -- which numbers are already used
    for i = 1, needed do
        local random
        repeat
            random = math.random( maximum )
        until not used[random]
        used[random] = true
        numbers[i] = random
    end
    return numbers
end
```

Comment: In case you are interested, I did some very informal timings on the solutions here. Mine was the fastest, but yours was second-fastest: both are O(n), but yours was about a constant factor of 10 times slower in my tests due to the need to get multiple random numbers when one has already been used. Yours is saved from O(n^2) since Lua table accesses are constant time, and you don't loop to check the array. The other solutions are O(n^2) (koyaanisqatsi) due to `table.remove` in a loop, and O(n^3) (WardyGuardian) due to `table.insert` in a loop, and the duplicate randoms combined.

Answer (score 0):

Making a table with 20 keys (use for/do/end) and then do your desired times

```
rand_number=table.remove(tablename, math.random(1,#tablename))
```

EDIT: Corrected - See first comment

> And rand_number never holds the same value. I use this as a simulation for a "Lottozahlengenerator" (german, sorry) or random video/music clips playing where duplicates are unwanted.

Comment: You need to fix the call to `table.remove`: `table.remove(tablename[math.random(1, #tablename)])` --> `table.remove(tablename, math.random(1, #tablename))`. This is a nice and concise solution, but is still O(n^2) in time complexity when you create a list using this. `table.remove` is not very efficient since it has to move all of the elements after the struck element towards the front of the array. But, at least this solution doesn't have the problem of choosing random numbers that have already been used.